# Is it possible to put OR Statement in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two field and I want exact functionality for both the field when the user (for example) blur out.

```
<input type = "text" class = "one">
<br>
<input type = "text" class = "two">

$(".one").blur(function () {
    alert("Hello");
});

$(".two").blur(function () {
    alert("Hello");
});
```

Can I merge these two in some elegant way? I don't want to Repeat the same code.

Something like:

```
$(".one") ||  $(".two")
    .blur(function () {
        alert("Hello");
    });
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put a comma, just as you would for a css selector:

```
$("#one, #two").blur(function () {
    alert("Hello");
});
```

See https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/.

But, FYI, your HTML is using classes (`class="one"`), and in your javascript you have ids (`#one`), you either need to do `id="one"` or use `.one` in your javascript.

A better solution would probably be like so:

```
<input type = "text" id="one" class="blurrable">
<br>
<input type = "text" id="two" class="blurrable">

$(".blurrable").blur(function () {
    alert("Hello");
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. And also, I added an edit section in my question to rectify the silly mistake I did while writing the demo example which you mentioned in `FYI`. But someone edited it took out the `EDIT` section and made the question proper. But now it made your `FYI` section invalid. I don't know how to deal with these kind of situation. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 4):

Check this link:
https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

```
$('#one, #two').blur(function() { /* ... */ });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it for all text inputs

```
            $("input[type=text]").blur(function () { alert("Hello"); });
```